# dispose method only works once then fails to function

Tags: java, swing, dispose

I'm having trouble with the functionality of dispose for my checkerboard (called Checkers) . For each checkerboard that I have, i want to be able to remove it by using dispose before calling another instance of my interface. Here is my progress so far:

```
Checkers class:

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;

public class Checkers extends JFrame
{
    Random random = new Random();
    private final int ROWS = 2;
    private final int COLS = 5;
    private final int GAP = 2;
    private final int NUM = ROWS * COLS;
    private int i;
    public int score;
    private JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS,COLS, GAP,GAP));
    private JPanel pane2 = new JPanel();
    private JPanel pane3 = new JPanel();

    private JButton btn1 = new JButton("Play A Game");
    private JButton btn2 = new JButton("Exit");

    private JButton btn3 = new JButton("Easy");
    private JButton btn4 = new JButton("Intermediate");
    private JButton btn5 = new JButton("Difficult");
    private JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel ("score: " + score);
    private JLabel gameLost = new JLabel("You lose! You got: " + score + " points");

    private MyPanel [] panel = new MyPanel[NUM];
    private Color col1 = Color.RED;
    private Color col2 = Color.WHITE;
    private Color col3 = Color.GREEN;
    private Color tempColor;

    public Checkers()
    {
        super("Checkers");
        setSize(600,600);
        setVisible(true);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setBoard();
    }

    public void setBoard()
    // roates colors on the checkbaord
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < panel.length; i++) {
            panel[i] = new MyPanel(this);
            pane.add(panel[i]);

            if (i % COLS == 0) {
                tempColor = col1;
                col1 = col2;
                col2 = tempColor;}
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                panel[i].setBackground(col1);}

            else {
                panel[i].setBackground(col2);}
        }

        //pane background colour and the size of this pane.
        pane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

        //pane background colour and size of this pane.
        pane2.setBackground(Color.white);
        pane2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

        //directions on the board where these panes appear.
        add(pane, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(pane2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        pane2.add(lbl1);

        pane2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane2, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    }

    public void incrementScore(){
        score++;
        lbl1.setText("Score: " + Integer.toString(score));
    }

    //This is the method for resetting via dispose - only works once.
    public void restartBoard(){
        this.dispose();
        new Checkers();

    }

}
```

And also the MyPanel class

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    private final Checkers checkers;

    public MyPanel(Checkers checkers) {

        this.checkers = checkers;

        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        checkers.incrementScore(); 

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {   
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { 
    }
}
```

**EXPECTED RESULT** - What i'd like to do is be able to close the current version of `interface` by using the `dispose` method, and then opening a new instance of said interface.

**ACTUAL RESULT** - When opening an interface, then calling `dispose` method, it will work once. once you try to remove the 2nd interface when creating a 3rd interface, `dispose` will not function, and I cant see why this is.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Your code post is not a valid [mcve], and so since we cannot compile, run, test and modify, we can only guess as to the problem, but the most obvious guess is that the `this` in the method only refers to the first Checkers instance. How to fix? Don't use this but rather a valid reference to the **currently displayed JFrame**. How specifically? I've no idea and ask that you create and post your [mcve] in your question to help us understand the exact nature of your problem and allow a valid answer that does not require guessing.

Comment: Also note this: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636). Most users do not like windows thrown at them, and if this were my GUI, I wouldn't do this but rather create and show one JFrame and then either reset the current JPanel to its initial state or swap JPanels using a CardLayout.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels code has been updated. This is runnable.

Comment: ? How can we run this code? there is no main method for instance. And even if it were runnable, nowhere does the code above call the `restartBoard()` method, and so we still cannot see the source of your error. For best help, please *read* or re-read the [mcve] link -- it will explain exactly what we need and why, and then re-[edit] your question.

Comment: Nevermind @HovercraftFullOfEels, I've seemed to have fixed the issue! just added another button onto the board, (I added the runnable main, thanks for pointing it out) then just added an actionlistener to call that restartBoard method when the button is pressed.

Comment: I'm glad that you've fixed the problem, but again please do consider swapping views and not windows. Luck.

Comment: Also for future questions about debugging a problem, do consider creating and posting a valid [mcve]. Guessing can be frustrating, and also the whole quality of the question and answer are vastly improved when this is done.

Comment: Please see answer for example [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and feel free to ask if any questions

Comment: I Will take a look shortly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this is an MCVE that shows your likely problem:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CheckersTest {

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Checkers checkers = new Checkers();

        JButton restartButton = new JButton("Restart");
        restartButton.addActionListener(event -> checkers.restartBoard());

        JPanel restartPanel = new JPanel();
        restartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        restartPanel.add(restartButton);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Checkers Test");
        frame.add(restartPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
class Checkers extends JFrame {
    public Checkers() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void restartBoard(){
        this.dispose();
        new Checkers();
    }
}
```

The restart button refers to the original Checkers instance and so will not close any new instances created. The solution would be to get the restart method *out* of Checkers, create a Checkers field, and make sure the restart method refers to the visible Checkers instance:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CheckersTest {
    private static Checkers checkers = new Checkers();  // holds reference

    private static void restartBoard() {
        if (checkers != null) {
            checkers.dispose();
            checkers = new Checkers(); // assign to reference field
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        // !! Checkers checkers = new Checkers();

        JButton restartButton = new JButton("Restart");
        // !! restartButton.addActionListener(event -> checkers.restartBoard());
        restartButton.addActionListener(event -> restartBoard());

        JPanel restartPanel = new JPanel();
        restartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        restartPanel.add(restartButton);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Checkers Test");
        frame.add(restartPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
class Checkers extends JFrame {
    public Checkers() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Notes:

- Again a much better design is not to swap JFrames but rather JPanel views
- Note that the MCVE has code that reproduces the problem but avoids code not related to the problem. So it shows the restartBoard method, it compiles, but avoids game code since this is not relevant to the problem.